# Replace single Activity with multiple Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

Is it possible to replace a single `Activity` using multiple `Fragment` objects?  If so, how would I go about handling the orientation changing?

Comment: Have you even tried something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to study alot to know what you are dealing with. First i recommend you to study about Fragments [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) and then follow [Using Fragments in Android - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html) and [Android User Interface Design: Working With Fragments -tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_fragments/)

To handle orientation changes follow the steps in this website: [Handling orientation changes in the Android UI framework](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/handling-orientation-changes-in-the-android-ui-framework/225)
[Follow build your first app](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) from android to practice app building and dont forget to check [android api examples](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html) which have tons of examples for fragments etc.